# How to use Zend 2 FlashMessenger component on none Zend project

Tags: php, session, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I am trying to add ZF2 FlashMessenger component  on my None Zend project. Please let me know the correct implementation.

I.e  I am trying following ex:

```
// Calling autoloader here 

use Zend\View\Helper\FlashMessenger;
$flash = new FlashMessenger();
$flash->addSuccessMessage("Test 1");
$flash->addSuccessMessage("Test 2");
$flash->addSuccessMessage("Test 4");

print_r($flash->getSuccessMessages());
```

Once I try this way, I am getting following errors

> Warning: Erroneous data format for unserializing 'Zend\Stdlib\ArrayObject' in Zend\Session\SessionManager.php on line 101
>   Warning: session_start(): Failed to decode session object. Session has been destroyed in Zend\Session\SessionManager.php on line 101

What I noted, Any how Zend Session manager not working properly with my project.

If any body can suggest, how tyo use ZF2 components on none ZF projects, it will be great.

Answer (score 2):

FlashMessenger is a part of the Zend\View MVC system.

You can't use it alone, you can install Zend\View component with Composer but the dependences are huge and configuration is not easy, the documentation recommend to start with the ZendSkeletonApplication base.

Comment: Yer, I have figured it out. Thank you very much.